# How to Modify Json Extractor?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql, data-lake

as Json Extractor works with valid Json formats. I have a problem in which I want Json without starting and ending square '[]' brackets.

My data is always in following format:

```
{
------
-----
-----
}
{
------
-----
-----
}
{
------
-----
-----
}
```

I won't be having the starting square bracket and the ending square bracket, More over, i won't be having the comma's between the two objects, can I modify the Json Extractor to work with this kind of problem.

If yes, how can we do that?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: if you remove the commas it's not a valid JSON anymore.

Comment: I know it won't be valid but can we modify Json Extractor to deal with it?

Comment: If your data is something like this [{..},{..},...], I would call it as an array of json objects. This would mean that you can cast the object as a list and use the json handler to iterate through the items. Have you tried that?

Comment: I actually don't want square brackets at start and end.

Comment: Hmmm, let's be clear here. First: How are you getting your data?

Comment: Did you make progress based on COR's suggestion? Also, do you expect CR/LFs in your JSON or is a JSON document always in a single row?

Comment: It doesn't matter if there is CR/LF or not, no progress till yet.

Answer (score 2):

This question is more a C# Programming Question than U-SQL.

Modifying the extractor in such a way that it reads the "wrongly" formatted json, won't be straightforward, since the JSON Extractor uses the newtonsoft json library to deserialize the string.

You might end up rewriting the extractor almost entirely.

A good starting point would be the Git Project:

https://github.com/Azure/usql/tree/master/Examples/DataFormats/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats/Json

But before all that, you might wanna check how you get the data